# Power locks unlock only (2002 Toyota Rav4)

Tags: toyota, locks, door, rav4

History: Front passenger and driver power locks didn't work. All other power locks worked fine -> Replaced front door lock actuators -> Now, all power locks (front and back) unlock only.

Comment: Does the car show that one of the doors is open all the time. It is common that that he power locks won't allow you to lock using the keyfob if one of the doors is open.